# Skipping lines, csv.DictReader

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a file that has an obnoxious preface to the header. So it looks like this:

```
Review performed by:    

Meeting:    

Person:     

Number:     

Code: 



Confirmation    

Tab Separated Header Names That I Want To Use
```

I want to  skip past everything and use the tab sep header names for my code. This is what I have so far:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(CSVFile)
for i in range(14): #trying to skip the first 14 rows
    reader.next()
for row in reader:
    print(row)
    if args.nextCode:
        tab = (row["Tab"])
        sep = int((row["Separated"]))
```

This code gets this error:

```
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/csv.py", line 104, in next
    row = self.reader.next()
StopIteration
```

I tried to print the rows, to see where I was in the file, and I changed the "range(14)" to range 5, but when I print the row, I get this:

```
{'Review performed by:': 'Tab/tSeparated/tHeader/tNames/tThat/tI/tWant/tTo/tUse'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 396, in <module>
    main()
  File "program.py", line 234, in main
    tab = (row["Tab"])
KeyError: 'Tab'
```

So I am not really sure the right way to skip those top lines. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your traceback does not match the posted code. Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A `csv.DictReader` reads the first line from the file *when it's instantiated*, to get the headers for subsequent rows. Therefore it uses `Review performed by:`     as the header row, *then* you skip the next 14 rows.

Instead, skip the lines *before* creating the `DictReader`:

```
for i in range(14):
    CSVFile.next()
reader = csv.DictReader(CSVFile)
...
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I didn't realize that it was when it was instantiated. Very informative!

Comment: A CSV row can span multiple lines. This is skipping the first 14 *lines* in the file, not 14 CSV rows.

Comment: @Boris true, edited to refer to skipping lines instead of rows.

Comment: @Boris: You can skip _rows_ by calling `next(reader)` one or more times, [iff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if) the data you want to skip is in CSV format — otherwise skipping lines is the only thing that makes sense.

Answer (score 14):

You could wrap the `CSVFile` with an [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) iterator object to slice-off the lines of the preface when creating the `DictReader`, instead of providing it directly to the constructor.

This works because the `csv.reader` constructor will accept "*any object which supports the [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator) protocol and returns a string each time its `__next__()` method is called*" as its first argument according to the [csv docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader). This also applies to `csv.DictReader`s because they're implemented via an underlying `csv.reader` instance.

Note how the `next(iterator).split()` expression supplies the `csv.DictReader` with a *`fieldnames`* argument (so it's not taken it from the first line of the file when it's instantiated) — so what @jonrsharpe said about the first line being read when the `DictReader` is instantiated isn't strictly true.)

```
iterator = itertools.islice(CSVFile, 14, None)  # Skip header lines.
for row in csv.DictReader(CSVFile, next(iterator).split(), delimiter='\t'):
    # process row ...
```